# Express handle routes with regex

Tags: express, routes

I have an route like as '/antalya-ucak-bileti' and 'antalya' word will be dynamically change. How can I handle it in routes?

I'm used NodeJS and ExpressJS

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
app.get('/:destination-ucak-bileti', (req, res) => {
  console.log('P', req.params.destination);
  res.end();
});
```